# How to round edges in Blender

Tags: bevel, smooth

I need to make a cylinder 4 cm in lenght, 4 cm in diameter, 2 mm thick.

The cylinder needs to be cut into the same shape it has in the photo I uploaded.
I used a bezier curve, screw and solidify tool. Then converted to mesh and used bisect.

It is very important that the edges are very round, like those of a glass or cup or a ring.

Is there a way to smooth edges or to make them round?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you may want to look into using bevels, sounds like what you're asking would best be achieved with a Subdivision Surface modifier (applied before export if you're making this for 3D printing).  You may need some loop cuts near the top and bottom to limit the rounding effect.

I'd recommend searching for Subdivision Surface and how to use it, you'll probably find that you don't need as much geometry as you're showing before using it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bevel modifier and set the edges to bevel by the angle. Also make sure "clamped" is ticked, this will ensure you can make the bevel as large as you want without geometry intersecting.

You can also just select the edges you want to round and use a "bevel edge" directly. Here also make sure to clamp your bevel and drag out the maximum bevel you can.